# Image upload to blog system issue

Tags: php

I am having an issue with 1 of my php files it is not uploading the image it adds to the database ok but no image in ../images folder ? and also I am getting the following error

> [28-Sep-2019 14:29:36 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable:
>   checked in /home/blog/admin/add-post.php on line 176

```
    <?php //include config
require_once('../includes/config.php');

//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Admin - Add Post</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/main.css">
  <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>
          tinymce.init({
              selector: "textarea",
              plugins: [
                  "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                  "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                  "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
              ],
              toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
          });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <?php include('menu.php');?>
    <p><a href="./">Blog Admin Index</a></p>

    <h2>Add Post</h2>

    <?php

    //if form has been submitted process it
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        // location where initial upload will be moved to
        $target = "images/" . $_FILES['postImage']['name'];
        $path = '../'.$target;

        //collect form data
        extract($_POST);

        //very basic validation
        if($postTitle ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter the title.';
        }

        if($postDesc ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter the description.';
        }

        if($postCont ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter the content.';
        }

        if(isset($_FILES['postImage'])){

            // find thevtype of image
            switch ($_FILES["postImage"]["type"]) {
            case $_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == "image/gif":
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["postImage"]["tmp_name"], $path);
                break;
            case $_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == "image/jpeg":
                   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["postImage"]["tmp_name"], $path);
                break;
            case $_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg":
                   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["postImage"]["tmp_name"], $path);
                break;
            case $_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == "image/png":
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["postImage"]["tmp_name"], $path);
                break;
            case $_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == "image/x-png":
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["postImage"]["tmp_name"], $path);
                break;

            default:
                $error[] = 'Wrong image type selected. Only JPG, PNG or GIF accepted!.';
            }

        }

        if(!isset($error)){

            try {

                $postSlug = slug($postTitle);

                //insert into database
                $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog_posts_seo (postTitle,postSlug,postDesc,postCont,postDate) VALUES (:postTitle, :postSlug, :postDesc, :postCont, :postDate)') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':postTitle' => $postTitle,
                    ':postSlug' => $postSlug,
                    ':postDesc' => $postDesc,
                    ':postCont' => $postCont,
                    ':postDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                ));
                $postID = $db->lastInsertId();

                if(isset($_FILES['postImage'])){

                    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE blog_posts_seo SET postImage = :image WHERE postID = :postID') ;
                    $stmt->execute(array(
                        ':postID' => $postID,
                        ':image' => $target
                    ));
                }

                //add categories
                if(is_array($catID)){
                    foreach($_POST['catID'] as $catID){
                        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog_post_cats (postID,catID)VALUES(:postID,:catID)');
                        $stmt->execute(array(
                            ':postID' => $postID,
                            ':catID' => $catID
                        ));
                    }
                }

                //redirect to index page
                header('Location: index.php?action=added');
                exit;

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        }

    }

    //check for any errors
    if(isset($error)){
        foreach($error as $error){
            echo '<p class="error">'.$error.'</p>';
        }
    }
    ?>

    <form action='' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <p><label>Title</label><br />
        <input type='text' name='postTitle' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postTitle'];}?>'></p>

        <p><label>Image</label><br />
        <input type='file' name='postImage'></p>

        <p><label>Description</label><br />
        <textarea name='postDesc' cols='60' rows='10'><?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postDesc'];}?></textarea></p>

        <p><label>Content</label><br />
        <textarea name='postCont' cols='60' rows='10'><?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postCont'];}?></textarea></p>


        <fieldset>
            <legend>Categories</legend>

            <?php   

            $stmt2 = $db->query('SELECT catID, catTitle FROM blog_cats ORDER BY catTitle');
            while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){

                if(isset($_POST['catID'])){

                    if(in_array($row2['catID'], $_POST['catID'])){
                       $checked="checked='checked'";
                    }else{
                       $checked = null;
                    }
                }

                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='catID[]' value='".$row2['catID']."' $checked> ".$row2['catTitle']."<br />";
            }

            ?>

        </fieldset>

        <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p>

    </form>

</div>
```

I have tried googling the error but unable to resolved i have checked re changed code but still no image upload the database is displaying the image but not the folder

Also there still issue on like 176 but the code looks right to me can someone give me some heads up whats wrong ?

Comment: fixxed issue with image upload now . but still issue with like 176

Comment: `code` 

            
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='catID[]' value='".$row2['catID']."' $checked> ".$row2['catTitle']."<br />";
            }

            ?>

        </fieldset>`code`

Comment: simply set an initial value for `$checked` outside the loop

Comment: can you advise me where abouts i put this im new to php learning

Comment: you can put `$checked='';` at the very top of the script if you wish - so long as it occurs before `while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){` you should be ok - that way at least it will be defined